# Get HTML of page with awesomium

Tags: html, c++, awesomium

How do I get the HTML of a web page in awesomium with *C++*?

I've searched and apparently you can only do it with webcontrol in *C#* or in *Java*. Using the sample hello I tried doing:

```
JSValue theVal( view->ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(WSLit("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML"),WSLit("")));
```

but it does not work. any ideas? and please in c++ as i am aware that you can do this in *C#* and *Java*.

Answer (score 4):

Using Javascript you can do it like this:

```
web_view->ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML");
```

also you can use:

```
web_view->CopyHTML();
```

and then get `HTML` from the clipboard. I am not sure if there is another way of getting `HTML` without using Javascript.